# XSLT find node by id and get the id of parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Im trying to get the id of the parent section from a section with specific id.

```
<xsl:variable name="path" select="ancestor::section[@xml:id='MyID']/@xml:id"/>
```

but thats not working ...

Is it possible to find a node by id and get the value of his first anchestor?

Comment: It would help if you showed a sample of your input XML. You probably also need to show more of your XSLT as it is relevant what node you are positioned on when you create that variable. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you use XSLT 2 or 3 and the input indeed has `xml:id` attributes on elements then you can simply use the `id` function to find them e.g. `id('MyID')` finds the element `<foo xml:id="MyID">..</foo>`.

Comment: When i find the element by id('MyID') how can i get the ancestor of this element? e.G for element <foo>

Comment: `id('MyID')` gives you the element and of course then you use normal XPath expressions like `id('MyID')/ancestor::bar` to find (a) certain ancestor(s)` or `id('MyID')/..` to find the parent node. And in a further step you can of course select an attribute e.g. `id('MyID')/../@xml:id` or `id('MyID')/ancestor::bar/@xml:id`.

Comment: thank you i get it and it works now!